# Prototypes and __proto__ in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, ecmascript-5

`Object` is a function
`Object.prototype` is an object whose constructor is `Object` itself.

But what is `Object()`?

can someone explain why this statement outputs `true`

```
Object.prototype.__proto__ === Object().__proto__.__proto__
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what is Object()?

Evaluating `Object()` produces a new empty object based on the Object prototype.

> can some explain why this statement outputs true
>
> `Object.prototype.__proto__ === Object().__proto__.__proto__`

`Object()` produces a new object which is based on the Object prototype. For an object created from a particular prototype, the `__proto__` is a reference to that prototype.

Therefore, it follows that `Object.prototype` and `Object().__proto__` both reference the same value:

```js
console.log(Object.prototype === Object().__proto__)
```

Since these both refer to the same thing, it also follows that your equality expression above is true. (incidentally `Object.prototype.__proto__` is `null`, so it would also be equal to any other `null` value).

Comment: Not the same case with `Function()`. That's why I was confused. So why Function() evaluates to an anonymous function?

Comment: @GauravChaudhary Because that's what it's designed to do. I don't see any reason to assume that `Function()` and `Object()` would do the same thing, but `Function()` _does_ create a value based on the Function prototype, which is analogous to what `Object()` does:  `Function().__proto__ === Function.prototype` is `true`.

Comment: Thanks! I got it but still I would like to know `typeof(Function())` is function but it acts like an object?

Comment: @GauravChaudhary In JavaScript, anything that is not a primitive is technically an object, so yes, functions are objects.

Comment: okay! So `Function()` is an object of type `function` right? @JLRishe

Comment: @GauravChaudhary Yes.

Answer (score 0):

It's true because both of them return null :)

```
Object.prototype.__proto__ === Object().__proto__.__proto__
```

Comment: and how about this `Array.prototype.__proto__ === Array().__proto__.__proto__` . These do not evaluates to `null`